# The webpage is zoomed in mobile firefox browser.

Tags: html, css

It is also zoomed if viewed in full screen mode on mobile chrome browser or if meta viewport is added.
The page is at https://agnelvishal.github.io/TrustingTrust/
Source code is at https://github.com/agnelvishal/TrustingTrust

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

inside the  `<head>` section of the HTML

Comment: We appreciate that you are only trying to help but this question does not meet our quality standards. Providing answers to such low quality questions only encourages equally low quality questions. You *might* wish to consider removing this answer in the interests of the site.